# I have a problem in javascript AJAX

Tags: ajax

The content of the text file is not displaying in the div tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc() 
{
    debugger;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","D:\Misc\LearningAJAX\ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you running this page? And in what browser?

Comment: I am running on IE or chrome and the page is on my pc. Is the Path syntax proper? should it be like this // or this /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","D:\Misc\LearningAJAX\ajax_info.txt",true);
```

Try

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","file:///D:/Misc/LearningAJAX/ajax_info.txt",true);
```

...but beware that using ajax from a document loaded with a `file://` URL, and retriving `file://` resources, is not all that reliable cross-browser. If you're trying to learn web development using your workstation, it's best to install a web server on it. There are lots and lots of web servers (not least [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/)) that will run on desktop machines.

Comment: @Chandan: I'd left off one of the slashes, but more to the point, using `file://` URLs with ajax is just problematic as heck. Strongly recommend using a locally-installed web server.

Comment: when i enter into debugging mode and when i execute the open statement it says access is denied.

Comment: I am not able to publish a website on Windows Vista. That is the problem i cant make it a web server.

Comment: @Chandan: Even on Vista, you can run a web server like Apache for local development. Again, trying to do ajax programming without actually using a web server will **not** work, the models browsers apply to `file://` vs. `http://` resources are just too different.

Comment: can u suggest me a site that guides how to install apache web server?

Comment: The one I linked in my question (http://httpd.apache.org/) has install guides. There are prebuilt binaries for Windows, with installers: http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache22  Pretty much point and shoot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because of security reasons browser will not let you make an AJAX call to a resource on a different domain or to any local resource.
So to get your example working you have to a). Upload the script to a web server and change the link to ajax_info.txt to absolute or relative OR b). run the script from localhost.

Something like:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "./data/ajax_info.txt", true);
```

Comment: I dont understand that why cant it pick from my localhost . why is it necessary to have this on a web server.

Comment: When you talk about 'localhost' do you mean web server running locally? If that's the case then it will work with the correction to the file path I mentioned earlier. The reason a browser will NOT let you load local file is because anyone can create a page like yours and do something like xmlhttp.open("GET", "C:\Users\Chandan\AppData\Outlook\passwords.dat", true); and then send data somewhere. As you can see this could be a serious security issue. It is the same reason why you cannot control value of <input type="file" /> with JavaScript or HTML.